# Ubuntu 12.04 Hangs On Login

Tags: 12.04, login, lightdm

Most of the time when I log in, I after I enter my password, it says login in, and nothing else happens.

Comment: The same thing has just started happening on my system too. Very frustrating!

Comment: experiencing this as well

Comment: Similar question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/130387

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I don't understand why this is off-topic.  It's a problem that multiple people, including me, have experienced and something that a desktop OS user would probably want solved. At a minimum the answers explaining that it is a bug are useful for someone who does a Google search about the problem and ends up here.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem after several updates were installed this morning.
To avoid more frustration, the solution I found was to install gdm and use it as my display manager.

`sudo install gdm`

It might not be the definitive solution.

Comment: By the way, this seems to be related to [this issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130265/ubuntu-12-04-hangs-on-login/130451#130451), but in my case I didn't install Ubuntu Tweak. The problem pops up spontaneously after a series of automatic updates.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and found out, that there is already a confirmed bug reported on launchpad for this problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/986967

I wrote a question for this problem on askubuntu myself with a bunch of log output ... [12.04: LightDM freezes while "Logging in..." - maybe due to deactivated login sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130592/lightdm-hangs-at-login-error-msg-in-auth-log-what-can-i-do)

maybe it's an authentication problem, because when I can login, this line in auth.log is present:

```
polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2 (system bus name :1.47 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale de_DE.UTF-8)
```

and when I have the problem, this line isn't there...

(I somehow can't comment so I wrote an answer... I hope that isn't rude or something)

edit: There is an unofficial bugfix posted in launchpad. I didn't try it yet.

> Michael Terry (mterry) wrote 6 minutes ago:
>
> Hello! I think I have a fix for this. See [https://code.launchpad.net/~mterry/unity-greeter/986967/+merge/104622](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Emterry/unity-greeter/986967/+merge/104622) for the techy explanation of why this happens.
>
> But if you want to test the fix or just are interested in fixing it soon, please try this ppa: [https://launchpad.net/~mterry/+archive/ppa2](https://launchpad.net/%7Emterry/+archive/ppa2)

edit: People in Launchpad report that the bugfix is working, and that the problem may be caused by deactivating the login sound with Ubuntu Tweak. Maybe reactivating the login sound might fix this problem too until a official update is available

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem too, several times. When the login screen hangs up, I switch to command line (CTRL+ALT+F1) and simply stop and start LightDM again. Annoying problem, for the moment I think I'll try this way, until the problem is fixed.

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo start lightdm
```

Comment: When I press Ctrl+Alt+F1, it asks for my password but it won't accept my password when I enter it. I tried it a few times to see if it was entered correctly.

Comment: @NaturistGirl numlock?