# 12.04: LightDM freezes while "Logging in..." - maybe due to deactivated login sound

Tags: 12.04, freeze, lightdm, authentication

good morning,

lightdm freezes often after I entered my passwort.
It hangs exactly saying "logging in...". It's no total system breakdown though.

I found out that there is already an existing bug report for that problem which affects a lot of people: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/986967

some people in Launchpad report that the problem may be caused by deactivating the login sound with Ubuntu Tweak. I've done that so it might be true.

There are 3 dupiclate question for this problem on askubuntu too:

[Ubuntu 12.04 Hangs On Login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130265/ubuntu-12-04-hangs-on-login/130902#130902)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/130721/12-04-lightdm-cannot-login/130922#130922

https://askubuntu.com/questions/130387/stuck-at-login-screen

Comment: Maybe it's the same problem like this:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/130387/stuck-at-login-screen

Comment: Yeah, it seems to me. I have the same error output you posted in your question. Do you also have the dbus error in your auth.log when the login gets stuck?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the official bugfix will be released - which should be soon - there are several ways to fix this problem:

1. Reactivating the login sound with Ubuntu Tweak (worked for me)
2. Installing the official bugfix which is in the "precise-proposed" repository now. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed
3. Switching to gdm as default display manager as indicated by sam until this problem is fixed.
4. Changing nothing and doing the following when the problem occurs:

   1. Pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1
   2. Logging in as admin user
   3. sudo restart lightdm
   4. Trying to login in lightdm again
   5. Repeating 1., 3. and 4. until the login is successful

(I did a bit of research and I'm now able to answer my question myself. I hope it's no problem)

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem, i installed gdm and logins in gdm than lightdm. light dm is a bug-gy.
for this at main login crtl+alt+f1 and sudo there and apt-get install gdm and activate it

Comment: thanks for your help. but I will stick to lightdm a little longer if that bug isn't to annoying. gdm is more like a workaround so I hope this bug will be fixed soon

Comment: lightdm is indeed not very robust, I triggered the login hang by applying the greeter numlockx fix without installing numlockx, that was enough to stop lightdm dead and throw the system into low-graphics mode!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that it is linked to custom wallpapers. I changed to a custom wallpaper and Ubuntu couldn't log in. It would simply hang at "logging in".

Following the steps above, changing the wallpaper back to a default, it works fine.

This should really be fixed.

Comment: There is an official bugfix in precise-proposed now. So the problem should be solved soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I added then removed the dodge feature from Unity (Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit)

This is what I did:

Using Synaptic Package Manager:

1. Uninstalled Unity
2. Uninstalled Lightdm
3. Uninstalled Ubuntu-Desktop
4. Re-installed Unity, Ubuntu-desktop, Lightdm

ALT + F2

unity --replace

I also reinstalled my Nvidia Graphic Drivers, has in the past caused issues after updates

Rebooted and it all came back working.

I did find I was able to log into a second account on my PC fine, so I think my profile was broken.

I then set my profile to auto logon in the USER menu.

I think it may have something to do with 'colord' (system service to manage device colour profiles), I noticed it kept crashing. Auto logon seems to be a solution, but compromises security..

The above process worked for me.

Thanks